# How to Split an Order if the order item row total is more than 1000

Tags: magento2

**For example**

Item 1 -> Row total = 400 add in order 1.

Item 2 -> Row total = 900 add in order 2.

Item 3 -> Row total = 600  add in order 1.

Item 4 -> Row total = 900 add in order 3.

Item 5 -> Row total = 100 add in order 2.

Please help me.